# Automatic Hand Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, gestures

I am developing an application for kids which does include a lot of animation. As a part of that I have to write a letter 'S' automatically on the GestureOverlay when an activity starts. It should be like a hand has to come and write the letter 'S' on the screen automatically when a particular activity is called. I have the image of a hand and the hand has to write the letter 'S'

Is that possible? How can it be achieved? Can anyone please help me?

Thanks a lot.